# Error when placing log4j2.xml under resources/xml

Tags: java, eclipse, hbase, log4j2

When I put my log4j2.xml under the resources/xml folder, I get the following error:
*ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.*

When I place it directly under resources.xml, it works perfectly. I have also given -Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/main/resources/xml/log4j2.xml under Run As->Run Configuration->Arguments tab. It doesn't work. What else can I do. Please help!

I also get this error log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory). with Hbase in the first case (under resources folder). How can I eliminate this?

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because Log4j2 is looking for log4j2.xml in the classpath. If you put it in src/main/resources/xml Maven is going to put it in classes/xml. The classloader will then only be able to find xml/log4j2.xml, not log4j2.xml.

The second error is because you have the log4j 1.x jar in your classpath but don't have any configuration for it.